# Bootstrap 4 Popover with formatted content

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

This is in an Angular 4 application.  I want to do a popover with HTML formatted content.   Looking at the documentation and cheat sheets I find this kind of example:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body"
    data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right"
    data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum        faucibus.">
  Popover on right
</button>
```

The popover content is contained in the **data-content** attribute value.

What I would rather have is a reference by ID to a section that contains the formatted content (includes tags/css).   Is there a different way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [NgbPopover](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/api) component from [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home). As explained in the [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples), it allows to include HTML in the popover content, supplied in a `ng-template` element.

You can see an example in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7EoUFiGaGYYiWhBPV2o8?p=preview).

```
<ng-template #popContent>
  <span style="color: red;">Hello</span>
  <span style="font-weight:bold;">{{name}}!</span>
</ng-template>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" [ngbPopover]="popContent" popoverTitle="Fancy content">
  I've got HTML in my popover!
</button>
```

Comment: This worked so I am going to mark it as an answer.   However the ng-bootstrap implementation leaves a bit to be desired.   For example if your popup is near the top border it is typical that it just cuts off the top part of it.

Comment: @AlanObject - The popover positioning is the subject of [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657179/ng-bootstrap-auto-popover-placement). A comment to that question mentions that [an issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/992) is open in the ng-bootstrap repository.